# aldeed:collection2 not working with iron cli

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am new to meteor iron and I am trying to install aldeed collection2 but the app is crushing

```
W20190215-12:44:48.023(2)? (STDERR) WARNING: npm peer requirements (for aldeed:collection2) not installed:
W20190215-12:44:48.024(2)? (STDERR)  - simpl-schema@>=0.0.0 not installed.
```

I have tried to install simple-schema but nothing is working.

```
meteor npm install simpl-schema --save
```

I have also removed and reinstalled collection2 but I still get the same error. What is it that I am missing?

Comment: Please add your Meteor release version, package.json and you .meteor/packages content so I can try to reproduce

Comment: meteor: 1.8.0.2
iron version: 1.8.1
package.json

    {
      "name": "wisdomapp",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "An app that teaches wisdom.",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
      },
      "author": "King Zuru",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "iron": "^5.0.6",
        "simpl-schema": "^1.5.5"
      }
    }

Comment: .meteor/packages

    meteor-base@1.4.0
    mobile-experience@1.0.5
    mongo@1.6.0
    reactive-var@1.0.11
    tracker@1.2.0
    standard-minifier-css@1.5.2
    standard-minifier-js@2.4.0
    es5-shim@4.8.0                # ECMAScript 5 compatibility for older browsers
    ecmascript@0.12.4              # Enable ECMAScript2015+ syntax in app code
    shell-server@0.4.0            # Server-side component of the `meteor shell` command
    iron:router
    blaze-html-templates
    twbs:bootstrap
    aldeed:autoform
    aldeed:collection2-core@2.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the error with a new created repo, that contains the dependencies you have listed but everything runs fine on my side.

However, I found, that`aldeed:collection2-core` is now somewhat deprecated and being merged back into `aldeed:collection2` as you can read in the [project repository on GitHub](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2-core/):

> MPORTANT: This package has been merged back into aldeed:collection2 as version 3.0.0 of that package. Refer to https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#300
>
> Create issues and PRs in the other repo going forward: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2/issues
>
> Issues remain enabled on this repo for reference to existing issues only.

So a good first step would be to remove the deprecated package and install the updated one:

```bash
meteor remove aldeed:collection2-core
meteor add aldeed:collection2
```

If you want to start from a new clean project you can reproduce these steps to get to a running starting point here:

```bash
meteor create someprojectname
cd someprojectname
meteor add iron:router twbs:bootstrap aldeed:autoform aldeed:collection2
meteor npm install --save iron simpl-schema
meteor
```

The project will start without errors. From here you can start including your former code and see if the error will come back (which is then likely to be an issue inside your code) or not.

## Important note on `twbs:bootstrap`:

The package `twbs:bootstrap` is using an [old version (3.3.6)](https://atmospherejs.com/twbs/bootstrap) which is considered to contain several security vulnerabilities (read [here](https://blog.getbootstrap.com/) and [here](https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2018/12/13/bootstrap-3-4-0/)).

If you want to use the latest Bootstrap you may rather install bootstrap using npm like so:

```bash
meteor remove twbs:bootstrap
meteor npm install --save bootstrap@latest jquery@latest popper.js@latest
```

You need `jquery` here, too because Meteor does not contain the required version and `popper.js` handles the Popover, Modal etc.

To include it in your code you need to add these lines to your client code:

```js
import 'bootstrap'
import popper from 'popper.js'
global.Popper = popper
```

To use Bootstrap 4 with AutoForm you can install `imajus:autoform-bootstrap4` ([repo](https://github.com/imajus/autoform-bootstrap4)) and add the following to your client code:

```js
AutoForm.setDefaultTemplate('bootstrap4')
```